# Attribute error while creating conda tensor flow virtual enviroment using python 3.9

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-venv

> C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab>conda create -n myenv python=3.6 Collecting
> package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
>
> ## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py",
> ```
>
> line 60, in **call**
> return cls._thread_local.session
> AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'session'
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
>     exit_code = do_call(args, p)
>   File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83,
> ```
>
> in do_call
> return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 41, in execute
> install(args, parser, 'create')
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 261, in install
> unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
> unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
> final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
> ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
> return f(*args, **kwds)
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 425, in _collect_all_metadata
> index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1020, in _prepare
> reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 276, in get_reduced_index
> new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 120, in query_all
> result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
> yield fs.pop().result()
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 432, in result
> return self.__get_result()
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
> raise self._exception
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 112, in 
> subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 125, in query
> self.load()
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 189, in load
> _internal_state = self._load()
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 259, in _load
> raw_repodata_str = fetch_repodata_remote_request(
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 485, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
> session = CondaSession()
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py",
> line 62, in **call**
> session = cls._thread_local.session = super(CondaSessionType, cls).**call**()
> File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py",
> line 85, in **init**
> retry = Retry(total=context.remote_max_retries,
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raise_on_status'
>
> `$ E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create -n myenv python=3.6`
>
> environment variables:
> CIO_TEST=
> CONDA_EXE=E:\Anaconda3\condabin..\Scripts\conda.exe
> CONDA_EXES="E:\Anaconda3\condabin..\Scripts\conda.exe"
> CONDA_ROOT=E:\Anaconda3
> CURL_CA_BUNDLE=
> HOMEPATH=\Users\Muhammad Tayyab
> PATH=E:\Anaconda3;E:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;E:\Anaconda3\Library\u
> sr\bin;E:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;E:\Anaconda3\Scripts;E:\Anaconda3\bin;
> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\Sys
> tem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;E:\Anaconda
> 3;E:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;E:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;E:\A
> naconda3\Library\bin;E:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\App
> Data\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\Muhammad
> Tayyab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Users\Muhammad
> Tayyab\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Muhammad
> Tayyab\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program
> Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin;
> PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Windows
> PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
> REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=
> SSL_CERT_FILE=
>
> ```
>  active environment : None
>    user config file : C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\.condarc  populated config files : C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\.condarc
>       conda version : 4.9.2 conda-build version : 3.20.5
>      python version : 3.8.5.final.0
>    virtual packages : __win=0=0
>                       __archspec=1=x86_64
>    base environment : E:\Anaconda3  (writable)
>        channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win64                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>       package cache : E:\Anaconda3\pkgs
>                       C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\.conda\pkgs
>                       C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
>    envs directories : E:\Anaconda3\envs
>                       C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\.conda\envs
>                       C:\Users\Muhammad Tayyab\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
>            platform : win-64
>          user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.6.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
>       administrator : False
>          netrc file : None
>        offline mode : False An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report. If submitted, this report will be
> ```
>
> used by core maintainers to improve future releases of conda. Would
> you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
>
> [y/N]: y Upload successful. Thank you for helping to improve conda.
> Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again) by
> running $ conda config --set report_errors true
>
> **I have tried everything but this shows everytime.**

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The same error showed up for me some time back, it looks like you have `pip installed` something that downgraded your version of `requests`; from the base environment [See this page for more info](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10183). Try this:

```
pip install requests==2.24
```